# Issue to get current time format from system using c#

Tags: c#

```
string dateFormate = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
```

With above code i can get current system date format whenever i change the date format in my system.

Ex: If i change date format like yy/MM/dd. i can get the same format as result. But i can't get correct current time format. even if i set date format like **hh:mm tt** in my system, always i am getting the format **h:mm tt**.

```
string timeFormate = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern;
```

the following image is showing where i can change the system date and  time format.

[image]

Comment: It sounds as though you've discovered a defect in the OS.  What version of Windows have you discovered this on?

Comment: .net ones are separate from windows.

Comment: Now i am using Windows XP Service Pack 3

Comment: @STLDeveloper Despite any windows/bug trolling, there's usually less bugs in windows than human misreadings/misunderstandings.

Comment: @X.L.Ant - Try not to get your panties in a bunch - I'm not trolling for anything.  It's obvious that the OS being used is windows from the posted images.

Comment: @STLDeveloper No offense meant, I was just saying that not every weirdness observed is necessarily a bug. I didn't mean you were trolling.

Comment: in the registry you can find sTimeFormat in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International is it changed to your value?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 DateTime result;


 if (DateTime.TryParse("31/1/2010", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-gb"), 
        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
            MessageBox.Show(result.ToShortDateString());    
    else
            MessageBox.Show("Not in Great Britain format");
```

> change en-gb ot en-us.  If you want to make the change permanant to the running appdomain, assign System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture to the GetCulture of en-us

Following code will return ShortDateFormat in the computer

```
MessageBox.Show(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern)
```

**Not Tried , only Reference**

REF:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat.aspx

REF:
 http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/01ecfe69-519f-400e-b08b-fa8979a7409e/how-to-detect-datetime-format-on-computer

Use the following link for LCIDs identifying cultures:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h88fahh(VS.85).aspx

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried the different cultures from CultureInfo. I came to the conclusion that only InstalledUICulture gets the changes on the OS settings. I tried it on Windows 7 Pro, though.

Does it work with CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture ?

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shorttimepattern.aspx

```
/*
This code produces the following output.

 CULTURE    PROPERTY VALUE
  en-US     h:mm tt
  ja-JP     H:mm
  fr-FR     HH:mm

*/
```

It is mentioned that ShortTimePattern will give h:mm tt for en-US culture as in screenshot.

That is why you get the behavior.